# Как прервать выполнение программы Java?

Tags: java

Знаю, что можно использовать System.exit(0), но против такого прерывания, это не совсем корректно. Один путь передаю с помощью аргумента, второй вбиваю. Хотелось бы узнать как прервать программу, если одного из путей нет.
Был ещё такой вариант:

```
if (path == null) return;
```

Но хотелось бы узнать какой вариант был бы более оптимален в моём случае. Потому что ветвления if/else не совсем люблю. Желательно, чтобы это обрабатывалось в catch.

```
public class Task implements AutoCloseable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String DownloadFile = "C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\Task\\src\\main\\resources\\Out.txt";
        Map<String, Departament> departments = new HashMap<>();
        String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

        read(path, departments);
transferToDepartment(departments, DownloadFile);
    }

    public static void read(String path, Map<String, Departament> departments) throws IOException {
        assert path != null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
            ...
            }
            System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Исправьте путь к файлу, выходите за массив");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
        }
    }

public static void transferToDepartment(Map<String, Departament> departments, String downloadFile) {
        ...
        uploadToFile(download, downloadFile);
    }

    private static void uploadToFile(List download, String path) {
        int i = 0;
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path, false)) {
            while (i < download.size()) {
                writer.write((String) download.get(i));
                writer.write('\n');
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
    }
}
```

Comment: Даже без специальных действий с Вашей стороны - вылетит исключение, Вы попадете в блок `catch` и программа завершится..., или я не понял вопрос...

Comment: К моему удивлению, когда программа попадает в блок catch, то ничего не прерывается, а работает дальше. Выводит сообщение "Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу" и не останавливается.

Comment: ну либо мы говорим не о приведенном участке кода, после read что то еще есть?

Comment: а так да, вы поймали исключение и выполнение пойдет дальше... либо пробрасывайте его выше, либо не ловите

Comment: Да, вы правы, у меня есть код дальше, добавил информацию о нём. А как его не ловить? Если проброшу выше, в main, то у меня там остановится или всё также пойдёт дальше работать?

Comment: как только исключение долетит до main метода - программа завершится, если вы его там не ловите при помощи `try-catch`

Comment: не ловить - объявить что метод кидает такие исключения.. или сразу один из общих типов

Comment: Хорошо, можете подсказать как мне объявить, что метод может кидать такие исключения?

Comment: вообще - через запятую, и еще, Вы не используете IDE? просто они это подсказывают

Comment: еще можно сделать просто `throws Throwable` но это считается bad practice

Comment: А, всё, я понял про что вы. У меня сейчас это вот так выглядит `public static void read(String path, Map<String, Departament> departments) throws IOException {`

Comment: да, вот после закрывающей круглой скобки идет перечисление исключений

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111664/discussion-between-blacit-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно изобретать велосипед ("украдите его").

Посмотрите любой приличный фреймворк на Application.Run, .... в  Application.Run у вас будет отлов исключения try catch и выход из основного приложения. Иначе говоря если исключение пробросилось catch(e){ throw e} до Application.Run то вывод/логирование/... и выход из Application.Run.

Comment: Application.Run -- это C#; но принцип подходит. Я описал более развернуто ниже.

Comment: Я не стал описывать а порекомендовал взять готовые решения. У spring тоже своя точка входа можно смотреть туда. Идея все таже. Это будет хорошим опытом прочтении исходников.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто нигде не ловить исключения. Всё будет работать, но вывод в консоль будет не красивый.

Можно вместо `println` бросать дальше свои исключения:

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  throw new MyPrettyException("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
```

А в самом конце `main`-a ловить:

```
} catch (MyPrettyException e){
   System.err.println("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
   System.exit(1)
}
```

`System.err` и `(1)` нужны, чтобы в случае вызова этой программы из другой программы можно было легко определить, что что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Тоже своё вариант ответа дал, который мне посоветовали, похож на ваш. Но без использования  `System.exit(1)` и `err`

Answer (score 0):

Мне дал этот ответ Stranger in the Q, привожу вариант, который использую.
Здесь мы пробрасываем исключения из метода read в главный метод main и там обрабатываем.

```
try {
            read(path, departments);
            transferToDepartment(departments, DownloadFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

public static void read(String path, Map<String, Departament> departments) throws IOException {
        assert path != null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
            ...
            }
            System.out.println("Читаемый файл закрыт");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Файл не был найден, проверьте путь");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Исправьте путь к файлу, выходите за массив");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Вы забыли прописать путь к файлу");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Есть 2 момента: 1) Если не делать свой класс _ожидаемых_ ошибок, то может случиться, что упало нечто, чего мы не предусмотрели, а стека для отладки мы не увидим. 2) если не делать System.exit(1), то если программу вызывает не человек напрямую, а скрипт, сложней определить, что что-то пошло не так